# OnServerValidate from UserControl

Tags: asp.net, validation, events

I have a custom user control which contains a textbox and some other logic / controls, including a custom validator.  When dropping my custom control on an aspx page, i want to be able to attach a method to the customer validator within the control, by providing a value for the OnServerValidate property in the html.

How can this be done?  I want to be able to pass the validation method name as a property in the user control's html, rather than having to attach to the custom validator's event through the code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap custom validator's `ServerValidate` event into your own, and then use it in the markup for the handler assignment. In you control all that is needed is a proper declaration of the event:

```
public event ServerValidateEventHandler ServerValidate
{
    add { this.CustomValidator1.ServerValidate += value; }
    remove { this.CustomValidator1.ServerValidate -= value; }
}
```

Now in the markup it is possible to sign up for this event, effectively signing up for the custom validator's event at the same time:

```
<yourTagPrefix:YourControlName
               OnServerValidate="YourControlName_ServerValidate"
               runat="server"
               ... />
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working... I added the event on my control, but when I try to sign up to the event from the markup, it is not showing up in the intellisense like the other properties.  If I add it just the same in the markup, it doesn't fire the event

Comment: What suggested here does not relate to the events firing. That's another problem and is more about how you trigger the validation. For proof of concept I have assigned two handlers for the CustomValidator - one in the user control, and one on the page via the suggested solution. In the Page_Load I simply call `Page.Validate()` and both of the handlers are called.